# Moving files to /dev/shm ramdisk doesn't increase RAM usage?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, tmpfs

I've been wanting to make us of a ramdisk on my Ubuntu system for a while, and have done a bit of reading online. Most of the advice centres around using /dev/shm to move files into RAM.

I wanted to try this out so I copied six 1GB files to /dev/shm, but according to gnome-system-monitor my RAM usage did not budge above 1.4GB. Is this how /dev/shm operates, or is there something else I need to do/use to ensure that files are stored in RAM and not on the HDD.

The reason I'm after the ramdisk is to speed up the analyses I run on this machine. Currently it uses at most about 1.6GB of the 24GB installed in the machine, and all that extra RAM doing nothing seems a bit of a shame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `/dev/shm`, that's for a special purpose.

Instead, do something like this if you want to experiment:

```
sudo mkdir /ram
sudo mount -t tmpfs none /ram
```

Files stored in tmpfs are stored in either ram or (if there's too much memory pressure) in swap.

I don't know why you don't see an increase.  Please post the actual commands you used, plus the output of the `free -m` shell command before and after.

You might like to read [this post about understanding free memory in Linux](http://www.sourcefrog.net/weblog/software/linux-kernel/free-mem.html) too.

The memory will be used to cache the files from disk, so it is actually in a sense helping, assuming your load has a multi-GB working set of files.  However, even heavily cached files do do some hard IO, and a ramdisk can be faster.

Comment: That implementation works great. Oddly, gnome-system-monitor does not show any increase in system RAM in the history panel, but `free -m` does.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question. "You shouldn't do that anyway, do this instead" remarks should go in comments.